# Set Calculator App for Shortcut Button

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, calculator

I have [one of those special "old" keyboards with extra keys](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DELL-Y-U0003-DEL5-Black-Wired-Slim-Multimedia-Keyboard-/232197378259) that allows you to open your "My Computer" ("This PC" in Windows 10), Mail Client, Web Homepage or Calculator with a press of a button.

I also have TI-NSpire CAS Software on my computer, which is useful for calculating more complex things like integrals (areas underneath a curve above the x-axis).

I know that it's possible to change your default mail and web client in the settings under [`Settings > Apps > Default Apps`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjJs8.png). However, my question is:

Is it possible to rebind the calculator app that Windows opens upon pressing the Calculator button?

The default calculator doesn't really cut it for calculating integrals and summations in their algebraic or equation format

Comment: "I'm on Windows 10" The tag is windows-10.

Comment: @DavidPostill Whoops... Didn't see the dash, but at least it's all fixed now ;)